# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied while trying to get token from ebay

Tags: c#, iis, ebay-api

**Using ASP .Net MVC 5, IIS 8.0.0.9, eBaySdk**

While I try to get token via SDK call, this error occurs. Of course after hosting. but  in visual studio, it works fine. What I think is, I have to set certain level of permission to allow users to use sdk or something like that. Here is the full error trace.

**Access is denied**

**Description**:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. 
>       Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) +773
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +123
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +49
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName) +31
>          eBay.Service.Util.SdkUtility.LaunchSignInPage(ApiContext Context, String SessionID) +671
>          VialinkerApps.App_Start.eBayApi.GetToken(UrlHelper url) +523
>          VialinkerApps.Controllers.SettingsController.AcceBay(eBaySetting
>   eBaySetting) +16
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +156
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2
>   parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>
> ```
>     System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
> ```
>
> result) +9
>              System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651796
>              System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 0):

Your user has not permission to access Win32Exception.

You can set administrator user with full permission or add permission to user.

In IIS `Manage->Pool Application->Advance Setting->Identity` change to `Custom Account` and set `Administrator` User with password